# Set Wno-dev in particular CMakeLists

Tags: linux, cmake, rpm

I have a project when I use cmake. I also use cmake to create a deb and an rpm package.
When building RPM we have many warnings like this:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackRPM.cmake:135 (message):
  CPackRPM:Warning: Path /etc/apache2/sites-available/mux.conf is not on one
  of the relocatable paths! Package will be partially relocatable.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackRPM.cmake:1001 (cpack_rpm_prepare_relocation_paths)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/Internal/CPack/CPackRPM.cmake:1870 (cpack_rpm_generate_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

We have many sub CmakeLists files and even when we use "-Wno-dev" at the top of the project we still have this warning.
How can I force the Wno-dev in the CMakeLists that cause this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Cmake-gui: Options|Warning Messages: Suppress Warnings - check "Developer Warnings"

From `man cmake`: cmake -Wno-dev ...